# document.getElementsByName doesn't work for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, click, getelementsbyname

I'm making a script in tampermonkey, that clicks on an element automatically.
The element I try to click is made like this when I inspect it in chrome:

```
<span id="result_5_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #FFD700;">Item | Anodized Navy</span>
```

¨

The script I tried to make goes like this:

```
function detectandclick {
    var item = document.getElementsByName('Item | Anodized Navy');

    item[0].click();
}
```

I'm new to programming, so there's probably something really wrong here.

PS: I do not want to use the getElementsById or class, I need to get the element by it's name displayed on the webpage.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You don't have `name` attribute, so how `document.getElementsByName` does not work?

Comment: That isn't it's name... that is it's text content or html content.

Comment: See [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) for usage

Comment: thank you guys for answering. Is there any way then I can refer to the text content?

Comment: Yes, but that's a different question. You could also take a look at [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) or even [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<span id="result_5_name" name="result_5_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #FFD700;">Item | Anodized Navy</span>
```

Now the below snippet will work:

```
function detectandclick {
  var item = document.getElementsByName('result_5_name');

  item[0].click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! My problem is I don't know how to change the HTML. I mean, it's a webpage I do not own, so I can't just change it, right? Also I need to do this for a lot of items so even if I could change it, I can't change it for all the item's, it would be too much, and some of them I can't even access. I can only refer to their text content :/ Thank you anyway!

Comment: In that case, just curious why would you not like to use 'getElementById' since the element does not have a 'name' attribute set as per your inspection in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName()` returns the elements of array of matched item, so you can use the index to access the particular item of array. Like

```
function detectandclick {
    var item = document.getElementsByName('somename')[0].click();
}

<span id="result_5_name" name="somename" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #FFD700;">Item | Anodized Navy</span>
```

More information about [getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)